# Dash python - images callbacks based on pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I have this df from an excel file:

```
URL Category    Tag1    Tag2    formatted
0   https://www.youtube.com/embed/K8L6KVGG-7o   Tutorial    Python  Regex   html.Iframe(src='https://www.youtube.com/embed...
1   https://www.youtube.com/embed/VPUX7nRlYAU   Docu    Mushroom    Fake leather    html.Iframe(src='https://www.youtube.com/embed...
2   https://www.youtube.com/embed/c6nurN-Hii8   Tutorial    Mushroom    Fake leather    html.Iframe(src='https://www.youtube.com/embed...
3   https://www.youtube.com/embed/K-v2erXztnY   Tutorial    Blender Geometry    html.Iframe(src='https://www.youtube.com/embed...
4   https://www.youtube.com/embed/1jHUY3qoBu8   Tutorial    Blender Low poly modeling   html.Iframe(src='https://www.youtube.com/embed...
```

and I wanted to create a dash app that would return the videos based on a dropdown menu list of choices, such as from Category or Tag1.

I was able to visualize all the videos in the app by creating an html.Iframe loop from the list of embeded video list, but was not able to make the dropdown menu to work.

What am I doing wrong in the callback?

Currently, if I select a value from the dropdown I return:

ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (5,), (1,))

and with no choices I get an empty frame.

```
urls_list = df['URL'].to_list()

app = dash.Dash(__name__) 

app.css.config.serve_locally = True
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True

""" videos = []
for url in urls_list:
    videos.append(html.Iframe(src=url)) """ 
videos = []
for url in urls_list:
    videos.append('(src='+"'"+url+"'"+')')

df['formatted'] = videos



app.layout = html.Div([
    
    html.Div([
                html.Div(className="header", 
                         children=[
                          html.Div(['YT Cat!'], id='title'),
                          html.Div([dcc.Link('Most viewed', href='', id='link-menu'),
                          dcc.Link('Newly added', href='', id='link-menu2')],
                         className='header-links')
                      ]),
                
                ], className='header-container'),
                
                       
    html.Div([
        html.Div([html.Img(id='logo')])
    ]),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown_main',
        options=[{'label':x, 'value':x} for x in df['Category'].unique()] + [{'label':x, 'value':x} for x in df['Tag1'].unique()],
        multi=True
    ),

    html.Div(id='video_placeholder'),#children=videos)
    
    ])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('video_placeholder', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown_main', 'value')]
)
def update_output(dropdown_value):
    return display_video(dropdown_value)

def display_video(dropdown_value):
    if dropdown_value == 'Tutorial':
       df[df['Category'] == 'Tutorial'].formatted
       
    elif dropdown_value == 'Docu':
       df[df['Category'] == 'Docu'].formatted

    return html.Iframe(df[df['Category'] == dropdown_value].formatted)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pandas.Series.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to check if elements in the series are contained in a container.

```py
filter_ = df['Category'].isin(dropdown_value)
filtered_df = df[filter_]

return filtered_df.formatted
```

Comment: great, thanks! and if I wanted to return another df['Tag1'].unique() that is coming from dropdown options, how I would updated my def?

Comment: Use `filter_ =  df['Category'].isin(dropdown_value) | df['Tag1'].isin(dropdown_value)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're have `multi=True` in your dcc.Dropdown, the dropdown_value parameter is a list, not a string. The ValueError is being raised when you try to evaluate

```py
df[df['Category'] == dropdown_value]
```

in your display_video function. That would work find if dropdown_value was a string, but it doesn't work if it's a list.

First, I would change your display_video function to something like this:

```py
def display_video(dropdown_value):
    if not isinstance(dropdown_value, list):
        dropdown_value = [dropdown_value]

    if not dropdown_value:
        return None
    elif 'Tutorial' in dropdown_value:
        return html.Iframe(df[df['Category'] == 'Tutorial'].formatted)
    elif 'Docu' in dropdown_value:
        return df[df['Category'] == 'Docu'].formatted
    else:
        return [html.Iframe(df[df['Category'] == dropdown_value[i]].formatted)
                for i in df[df['Category'].unique()]]
```

After that, I'm still not completely clear on how you want the app to work so I'd need some more details.

Comment: @djcunnigham0 thank you for the reply. It returns: KeyError: "None of [Index(['Tutorial', 'Docu'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]" . In general, I'd like the app to show the embedded urls in the dataframe as videos, with the dropdown acting as a filter depending on what category or tags you are selecting.